# Nsis installer icon image missing

Tags: nsis

I made an installer in NSIS. When i'm installing it on Windows 7 everything is perfect.

When i do same on Windows XP the icon of the installer is missing. 
Also when the installer finished the shortcuts icons images are missing as well.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the maximum icon size for XP is 32x32.

If you are using an icon made for Win7 that is bigger than 32x32 and that does not include alternative sizes (32x32, 16x16), it is likely that the icon won't be displayed correctly on XP.

Comment: I think u might be the point my icones are much bigger then that